# How to retrieve firestore nested array and map and show this in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

In my app i want show recyclerview under another recyclerview,and this data coming from Firebase Firestore.It's showing perfectly but the nested recyclerview show same item in other nested recyclerview.

My database structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqz1z.png

My code
This is the parent recyclerview model
OrderModel.kt

```
@Parcelize
data class OrderModel(
var userId:String? = null,
var orderId:String? = null,
var orderItem:List<AddToCartModel>? = null,
var address:AddressModel? = null,
var paymentType:String? = null,
var orderDate:String? = null,
var totalPrice:Int? = null,
var orderStatus:String? = null
):Parcelable
```

This is the nested recyclerview model
AddToCartModel.kt

```
@Parcelize
data class AddToCartModel(
var productId:String? = null,
var productImage:String? = null,
var productName:String? = null,
var productColor:String? = null,
var productColorName:String? = null,
var productQuantity:Int? = null,
var productPrice:Int? = null,
var productSinglePrice:Int? = null,
var productOrderId:String? = null
):Parcelable
```

OrderGroupAdapter.kt

```
class OrderGroupAdapter(var clickListener: ClickListener<OrderModel>) :
BaseAdapter<OrderModel, OrderGroupRowBinding>() {

private var orderGroup = ArrayList<OrderModel>()
private var orderItem = ArrayList<AddToCartModel>()
private val adapter by lazy {
    OrderItemAdapter()
}

private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var currentUser: FirebaseUser
private lateinit var currentUserId: String

override fun getLayout() = R.layout.order_group_row

override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: Companion.BaseViewHolder<OrderGroupRowBinding>,
    position: Int
) {
    holder.binding.orderGroupModel = itemList[position]
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.onClick(itemList[position], position)
    }

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    currentUserId = currentUser.uid

    db.collection("Users").document(currentUserId).collection("Order")
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            for (doc: DocumentChange in value!!.documentChanges) {
                orderGroup.add(doc.document.toObject(OrderModel::class.java))
                Log.i("modelData", "onBindViewHolder: $orderGroup")
                orderGroup.forEach { modelData ->
                    orderItem = modelData.orderItem as ArrayList<AddToCartModel>
                    adapter.addItems(orderItem)
                    setUpRecyclerView(holder)
                }

            }
        }
 }

private fun setUpRecyclerView(holder: 
BaseAdapter.Companion.BaseViewHolder<OrderGroupRowBinding>) {
    holder.binding.orderItemRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
        EcommerceApp.getApp()!!.applicationContext,
        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false
    )
    holder.binding.orderItemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    holder.binding.orderItemRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
}
```

Edit 1:
to better understand i attach the the view.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Vf1.png

How can i show the right data in each parent recyclerview? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "nested recyclerview show same item"?

Comment: i have a recyclerview under recyclerview,the parent recyclerview show OrderModel.kt data and nested recyclerview show AddToCartModel.kt data.the parent recyclerview show actual data but nested recycelerview show same AddToCartModel data.

Comment: Are you using the same instance of your adapter?

Comment: i can't get it, can you please explain?

Comment: for better understanding i added my view and database structure.@Alex Mamo

Comment: How are you populating the outer RecylerView?

Comment: first i get the "Order" collection then start a for loop, this loop provide me all Order and i convert this model and again start a loop to get a all orderItem

Comment: I also add the code, database and ui